# Flutter not running after updating to 2.8.1 on IOS but working fine on Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, frameworks

it's been 4 days since I am stuck with this error. I updated from 2.2.3 to 2.8.1 and then I am having issues on running IOS. It's throwing me the following error for framework not found.

```
/Volumes/PageSuiteWork/Projects/Flutter/Feed/ios/Runner/ReaderArticleViewController.swift:230:13: warning: initialization of immutable value 'fontSize' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
```

```
_
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Volumes/PageSuiteWork/Projects/Flutter/Feed/ios/Frameworks'
ld: framework not found url_launcher
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Compile Sources build phase: /Volumes/PageSuiteWork/Projects/Flutter/Feed/ios/Runner/LocalizationHelper.swift (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
If I remove Url_launcher from IOS build then it will throw for other frameworks.


I have tried installing, removing, upgrading flutter, and everything I can find on Internet but it will throw the same error. It runs normally on Android.

Flutter Doctor :

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
Run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
✗ Android license status unknown.
Run flutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```